# retain angular variables after page refresh without localStorage?

Tags: angular

How to retain angular variables after page refresh without localStorage ?

localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
localStorage.getItem("key");

Comment: If you don't like localStorage you wont like the other options either, because all would be on the browser, like sessionStorage, Cookies or using IndexedDB. Why do you need to retain the variables and why you do not want to use localStorage?

Comment: As Luiz stated. Unless you want to store state in the URL - also possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them to the URL as parameters then on refresh, read them from route snapshot.

Comment: as this way ?
 this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("carBrand")

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this by using session storage or local storage.
Another way to do it is to store data in a real time database, using a real time database will make data available through all devices